# Calling a list of rest api's from a route builder of a apache camel

Tags: java, apache, rest, routes, apache-camel

I want to call a list of restApi's from a route builder when an object is being saved.

The list of rest API hosts will be taken from the properties file for time being I had hard coded it in code itself.

I didn't find any forEach loop to be used in `RouteBuilder`

```
public class userApiRoute extends BaseApiRoute {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        super.configure(); String   hosts="http://127.0.0.1:10080/api.notification,http://123.123.123.123:10080";
        List<String> hostList = Arrays.asList(hosts.split("\\s*,\\s*"));

        rest("/api/user").post().description("Updates a User document")
        .type(User.class).consumes("application/json").route().routeId("UpdateUser").to("authService")
        .policy("apiUserPolicy").beanRef("userDefService", "save").choice().when(ifCSV)
        .to("userDefinitionFileNotifier").marshal(csv)
        .to("file://{{user.notification.location}}").when(ifMessaging)
        .to("userDefinitionMessageNotifier").wireTap("jms:queue:{{user.notification.location}}").
.to("userDefinitionApiNotifier")
.recipientList(constant("http://localhost:8081/api/test-api,http://localhost:8081/api/test-api2,http://localhost:8081/api/test-ap3"),",").aggregationStrategy(new userAggregationStrategy())
//.recipientList(constant("properties:{{api.hostList}}"),",").aggregationStrategy(new userAggregationStrategy())

        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(201)).endRest();
    }
}
@Component("userDefinitionApiNotifier")
public class UserDefinitionApiNotifier implements Processor {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    String id = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("id");
    log.debug("creating message for - {}", id);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("RECORD_TYPE", "Config_Update");
    jsonObject.put("ID", id);
    jsonObject.put("TYPE", "UserDefinition");

    if (jsonObject != null) {
        exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, "POST");
        exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        exchange.getOut().setBody(jsonObject.toString());
    }

}
public class userAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
@Override
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
    log.debug("Aggregrator Start" );
    if (oldExchange == null) {
        log.debug("Aggregrator stop" );
        return newExchange;
    }
    String oldBody = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    String newBody = newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    String newUri = newExchange.getProperty(Exchange.RECIPIENT_LIST_ENDPOINT, String.class);
    String oldUri = oldExchange.getProperty(Exchange.RECIPIENT_LIST_ENDPOINT, String.class);
    log.debug("Aggregrator old body {}",oldBody );
    log.debug("Aggregrator body {}", newBody );
    log.debug("Aggregrator newuri {}", newUri );
    log.debug("Aggregrator olduri {}", oldUri );
    oldExchange.getIn().setBody(oldBody + "+" + newBody);
    log.debug("Aggregrator End" );
    return oldExchange;
}
```

}

The websites I referred to are [httpComponent](http://camel.apache.org/http.html) and [loop](http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/loop.html).

Comment: Why do you need a loop? Split the list and call the API based on the value of each split which you can set in a header property

Comment: I want to iterate over a list of API addresses and send a post request to each Api with setting some object data.

Comment: You can do that with a splitter pattern as well.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti I am unable to find out how I can give the splited rest api as a uri to send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually use recipientList to publish the message in one shot to all your addresses

```
.recipientList(method(<return your list of addresses>))
```

but if you want to iterate and push ,

Save the message object that is your message body in a exchange property and apply the split over your list of addresses to which you want to post this object. During each iteration simply publish the message from the property to the address in the body.

```
.setProperty("message",body())
.split(method(<return your list of addresses>))
.setProperty("toAddress" , body())
.transform(exchangeProperty("message"))
.recipientList(exchangeProperty("toAddress"))
```

Note : make sure the addresses are formated to match the endpoint structure according to your component

Comment: @Component("userDefinitionApiNotifier")
public class UserDefinitionApiNotifier implements Processor {
 private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
 @Override
 public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
  String operation = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("OPERATION");
  Map<String, String> message = new HashMap<String, String>();
  message.put("config", operation);
  if (message.isEmpty() == false) {
   exchange.getOut().setBody(message);
  }
 }
}
and in route 
.to("userDefinitionApiNotifier").recipientList(hostList );
is the above enough

Comment: yes comma separated string of endpoints will work for recipientList according to the doc .. so it should work. you must give it like this .recipientList(constant(hostList),"," );

Comment: can we map the response of each call to a class? , and will this be a post request?

Comment: If you want to process the reponse from each of the recipients then use an aggregation strategy to process each response and produce a consolidated result   .recipientList(constant(hostList),"," ).aggregationStrategy(new AggregationStrategy(){  public void aggregate(Exchange old , Exchange new){ // your code to process the body from new}})

Comment: sagar RecepientList wont work for my need , I want to send a post request with same request body to different rest api's. .but when i use recepient list. .it will take body as url and gives nosuch endpoint exception
jsonObject.put("RECORD_TYPE", "Config_Update");
jsonObject.put("ID", id);
jsonObject.put("TYPE", "ProgramDefinition");
exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, "POST");
exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
exchange.getOut().setBody(jsonObject);
this is how i create request object and i calls
.recipientList(List).tokenize(",")

Comment: It shoud work.. can you post your code?!.Did you try giving it as constant .recipientList(constant(comma-seperated-string-of-endpoints)).tokenize(,) ?!!..

Comment: @Component("testDefinitionApiNotifier")
public class TestDefinitionApiNotifier implements Processor {
private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
@Override public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
String id = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("id");
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("TYPE", "Update"); jsonObject.put("ID", id);jsonObject.put("TYPE", "Def");
exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, "POST");exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");exchange.getOut().setBody(jsonObject);}}}

Comment: public class programAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {
 @Override
 public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
 if (oldExchange == null) {
    return newExchange;
  }
  String oldBody = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
  String newBody = newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
  String newUri = newExchange.getProperty(Exchange.RECIPIENT_LIST_ENDPOINT, String.class);
  oldExchange.getIn().setBody(oldBody + "+" + newBody);
 
  return oldExchange;
}
}

Comment: And in route Provider
.to("programDefinitionApiNotifier")
.recipientList("{{test.hostList}}").tokenize(",").aggregationStrategy(new programAggregationStrategy())

Comment: @Arjun  you can edit your post and add the code to the post , I couldn't read your code properly .. but from what you have pasted I don't understand how you are  setting value to `test.hostList` in `.recipientList("{{test.hostList}}")` . If you are using Properties component you plz refer [Properties component][1]


  [1]: http://camel.apache.org/properties.html

Comment: the recepientList is working fine when I give the list of url's directly as shown in code. But when I try to give list of url string from properties file(shown in commented code) then the recpientList is taking whole list as single Url

Comment: try using simple expresion instead of constant *.recipientList(simple("properties:{{api.hostList}}"),",")*

Comment: when I use simple am getting error when the list as only one element
The error isBody:[Body is instance of java.io.InputStream]

Answer (score 0):

Try using simple expresion instead of constant `.recipientList(simple("properties:{{api.hostList}}"),",")`

If you find it still not working .. then save the field in a exchange property .. 
.setProperty("hostList" , simple("properties:{{api.hostList}}"))
and then use `.recipientList(exchangeProperty("hostList"),",")`